# Command terminated when inputting large number

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

How come do I get a message "Command terminated" when I try to input a large number (around 10 million)?  The program displays whether the number is a prime or not.

See code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   unsigned long long number;
   bool prime ( unsigned long long );

   printf ("Enter a positive integer greater than 1: ");
   scanf ("%llu", &number );

   prime( number ) ?
      printf ( "%llu is a prime.\n", number ):
      printf ( "%llu is not a prime.\n", number);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool prime ( unsigned long long number )
{
   unsigned long long i, j;
   bool isPrime[number + 1];

   for ( i = 2; i <= number; i++ )
      isPrime[i] = true;

   for ( i = 2; i <= number - 1; i++ )
      for ( j = 1; i*j <= number; j++ )
         isPrime[i*j] = false;

   return isPrime[number];
}
```

Comment: The line `bool isPrime[number + 1]` compiles without an error?

Comment: @barakmanos it's C, not C++ (C99 supports variable length arrays)

Comment: At least for me, yes.  I am using GCC.

Comment: @MarcoA: That works for both! In any case, there is probably not enough stack space for a 10 million `bool` array.

Comment: You're probably blowing your stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you attempt to create an array `isPrime` on the stack that is larger than the available memory. You should create it on the heap instead, using

```
bool *isPrime;
isPrime = malloc((number + 1) * sizeof *isPrime);
```

do this only once obviously, not for every call to the function `prime`

Notice also that if you just want to know if a number is prime, you only need to search as far as the square root of the number for a factor - and if you find a factor you are done. This makes the size of the array you have to create much more manageable - but it does involve some changes to your algorithm.

**afterthought** you have a problem in the logic that determines what is a prime number - your inner loop starts with `j=1` which means that even prime numbers will be marked as non-prime.  The following is "slightly improved" code - although there's more you could do to make it much better:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   unsigned long long number;
   bool prime ( unsigned long long );

   printf ("Enter a positive integer greater than 1: ");
   scanf ("%llu", &number );

   prime( number ) ?
      printf ( "%llu is a prime.\n", number ):
      printf ( "%llu is not a prime.\n", number);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool prime ( unsigned long long number )
{
   unsigned long long i, j, sq;
   bool *isPrime;
   sq = ceil(sqrt(number));
   isPrime = malloc((sq + 1)*sizeof *isPrime);

   // generate primes up to the square root of the number
   for ( i = 2; i <= sq; i++ )
      isPrime[i] = true;

   for ( i = 2; i < sq; i++ ) {
      // only need to mark multiples if this is a prime:
      if(isPrime[i]) {
        // start this loop at 2, not 1!
        for ( j = 2; i*j <= sq; j++ ) {
          isPrime[i*j] = false;
        }
      }
    }

   for ( i = 1; i < sq; i++)
   {
    if (isPrime[i] && number%i==0) return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Basic testing:

`gcc -Wall` generates no errors / warnings

`104729` is a prime (it is); code doesn't crash with an input of `10000001` (not a prime).

Comment: /agree, I'm getting stackoverflow :)